# How to interactively edit a file name from the terminal like with a file manager?

Tags: command-line, rename, editors, interactive

At the command line, one can rename a file by specifying the entire new name to `mv`

```
mv oldname newname
```

or using a regex with e.g. Perl's `file-rename` command.

```
rename -d 's/old/new/' oldname
```

But is it possible to interactively rename a file by manually moving a cursor and changing bits of it, like when one renames a file in a file manager?

[image: File-manager rename]

Comment: It is Shift+F6 in Midnight Commander. (Shift+F4 if F16 is misconfigured.)

Answer (score 1):

Use [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/)'s `vidir`.

```
vidir oldname
```

will open the file path in `$EDITOR` (which can be either a text-based editor or a graphical one such as `codium -w`). E.g. with `nano`:

[image: vidir with nano]

One can give as many files as desired to `vidir` as its primary use case is to rename many files at once:

```
vidir mydir/*
```

Answer (score 1):

Could be done in a script like:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
zmodload zsh/system
ret=0
for old do
  new=$old
  ERRNO=0
  if [[ ! -e $old && ! -L $old ]]; then
    syserror -p "$old: "
  elif
    vared -p "Renaming $old:q to: " new &&
      [[ -n $new && $old != $new ]]
  then
    mv -iv -- "$old" "$new" || ret=$?
  fi
done
exit $ret
```

Note that if the destination file (`$new` edited by `vared`) ends up being a file of type *directory* (or symlink to directory), as usual, `mv` will try to move the source (`$old`) file *into* it. With GNU `mv`, you can add the `-T` option for it to try and rename the file to that instead.

The `bash` shell has `IFS= read -rep Prompt -i "$old" new` to do something approaching zsh's `vared` (`var`iable `ed`itor), but it doesn't  work properly for file names containing newline characters¹.

---

<sup>¹ With recent versions, adding `-d ''` allows multiline file names to be entered, but then you need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>@</kbd>/<kbd>Space</kbd> (whatever combination your terminal sends a NUL on) to accept the new file name.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I created a [lightweight command-line renaming utility](https://github.com/fonic/infiren) that, among other features, allows direct editing via its `edit` command:

[image]

Project home:
https://github.com/fonic/infiren

Dependencies:
Bash, GNU find